# When I run lscpu, then what does "Stepping" mean?

Tags: cpu

I understand other machine characteristics but the meaning of "stepping" is still not clear to me.

Is this perhaps related to Speedstep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [a version number](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-001665.htm). The processor design is tweaked or fixed over the course of the product lifetime, and the stepping number identifies how old (or new) it is.

See also:

- [Stepping level on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_level)
- [What is the difference betwwen two Xeon CPUs with stepping 11 and 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/344394/what-is-the-difference-betwwen-two-xeon-cpus-with-stepping-11-and-7)